# How can I not open a link in jQuery UI

Tags: php, jquery-ui

I use **jquery-ui** (v1.12.1).

> https://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax  (TABS LOAD AJAX)

```
$( function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs({
        beforeLoad: function (event, ui) {
            $('#preloader').show();
            if (ui.tab.data("loaded")) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $('#preloader').hide();
                return;
            }
            ui.ajaxSettings.cache = false,
            ui.panel.html('<img src="assets/ajax-loader.gif"> Loading...'),
            ui.jqXHR.success(function() {ui.tab.data( "loaded", true ); $('#preloader').hide();
            }),
            ui.jqXHR.error(function () {ui.panel.html("Couldn't load Data. Plz Reload Page or Try Again Later."); });
        }
    });
});
```

I want to **not** open the **tabs** "**herf**" in the form of a link.

```
<div class="part" id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="ajax/content1.html">Apple</a></li>
    <li><a href="ajax/content2.html">Samsung</a></li>
    <li><a href="ajax/content3.html">Sony</a></li>
    <li><a href="ajax/content4.php">HTC</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

What's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified this code.
I have extracted the following code from this site:

```
http://demo.webslesson.info/jquery-ui-tooltip-with-ajax-php/
```

But I want to write as the tab of Ajax.

index.php

```
<?php
include('database_connection.php');
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_student ORDER BY student_name ASC";
$statement = $connect->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
?>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="part" id="tabs">
  <ul>
         <?php
         foreach($result as $row)
         {
          echo '<li><a id="'.$row["student_id"].'" href="#">'.$row["student_name"].'</a></li>';
         }
         ?>
  </ul>
</div>
<script>  
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("#tabs").tabs({
        beforeLoad: function (event, ui) {
            $('#preloader').show();
            $.post('fetch.php', { id:$(this).attr('id') }, function(data){ result(data); });
            if (ui.tab.data("loaded")) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $('#preloader').hide();
                return;
            }
            ui.ajaxSettings.cache = false,
            ui.panel.html('<img src="assets/ajax-loader.gif"> Loading...'),
            ui.jqXHR.success(function() {ui.tab.data( "loaded", true ); $('#preloader').hide();}),
            ui.jqXHR.error(function () {ui.panel.html("Couldn't load Data. Plz Reload Page or Try Again Later."); });
        }
    });
});  
</script>
```

fetch.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["id"]))
{
 $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_student WHERE student_id = '".$_POST["id"]."'";
 $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute();
 $result = $statement->fetchAll();
 $output = '';

 foreach($result as $row)
 {
  $output .= '
  <img src="images/'.$row["image"].'" class="img-thumbnail" />
  <h4>Name - '.$row["student_name"].'</h4>
  <h4>Phone No. - '.$row["student_phone"].'</h4>
  ';
 }
 echo $output;
}
?>
```

When I click that tab, That text doesn't show.
Is jQueryUI code loaded incorrectly?